# Google Big Query Connection to Alteryx Using the Simba ODBC Driver

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having trouble connecting to my Google BigQuery Data through the Simba ODBC Driver. It only connects sporadically and gives me the below error message.

> Error: Input Data (72): Error SQLDriverConnect: [Simba][BigQuery]
>   (100) Error interacting with REST API: Failure when receiving data
>   from the peer

I've been working with the Alteryx team and my internal IT team but can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know if there are there any size limitations of queries coming from Alteryx? Or other issues to look into?

Thanks!

Comment: try to add to the connection string `".......;timeout=3600"`

Comment: Where would I add that?

Comment: It should be somewhere on your gui

Comment: I'm sorry, not exactly sure where it would go in Alteryx. I don't see anywhere under the ODBC Simba connection setup that asks for a connection string.

Comment: Agree with @Pentium10, It is most likely a connection issue rather than the size limitations of queries.